# How to apply geonodes while retaining UV mapped geometry materials?

Tags: texturing, materials, export, geometry-nodes, unreal-engine

I've seen similar questions but this one is probably the most edge case.
I have geometry with UV mapped textures:
[image]

[image: Geonodes setup for signs scattering]

But when I toggle realize instances:

[image]

Moreover I'm instancing meshes with dual slots for its materials:

[image]

Is it simply not possible? I'm trying to export this to unreal engine 5 using Datasmith format. Would highly appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use the `Realize Instances` node?

Comment: One more try: You obviously only use instances and existing geometry here, which you transform, and don't create any geometry with *Geometry Nodes*. Then why do you use the node `Realize Instances` at the end?

Comment: @quellenform sorry for the late response. Applying geometry without realize makes the geometry disappear upon application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution for this problem: Use **Blender 3.2+**.

[image]

Previous versions unfortunately discarded the *UVMaps* of the instantiated objects as soon as the node `Realize Instances` was applied.

[image]

Comment: Wait a sec... Am I supposed to have the same materials as instances on the source geometry for GN or having it just on instance source objects suffice? From your screenshot it seems you have the cube materials in your plane geo as well. And also, is having UV map node as texture vector important (in shader editor) for geonodes to correctly apply?

Comment: In this case you would have to apply the material to the original objects, or assign it via `Set Material`. The material on the object containing the geometry nodes is irrelevant.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot for your help. I'll see if I can get it to work..